# Can I make an Android app interact with a website off-screen?

Tags: java, android

So I'm looking to make an app just for a friend and myself that will take a string as input from the user, type that into a search box on a website, and do something on the first result.  For example, if the user typed in "a" it could direct them to the first result of googling "a."  I've done a lot of research and haven't found any ways. Does anyone know if Selenium works for this?

Comment: Are you looking for Google Search API?

Comment: No. It's a different site. That was just an example. Sorty

Comment: Depends on the structure of the site, it will have lots of ways to request and get these results. It may use HttpRequest technical for simply if you can trace the API (Ex: F12 in Chrome, Network tab), or XPATH XSLT parser even Selenium with more complex. So it's not generic for all sites, could you give me the site that you want to get from?

Comment: I want it to return a link to a YouTube video that is the first result of a given query. So there is a version of Selenium that would work with Android?  If so, I know how to use Selenium

Comment: Ok basically with Youtube site it will be easier and doesn't need Selenium because of bad performance. I suggest you using Youtube Data API, it will return the json format so you can be easier to parse the link. Try this request form, it might help you https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=surfing&_h=1&